# X11 forwarding in nested SSH connection

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ssh, x11, xforwarding

I am aware that X11 forwarding is a pretty hot topic. I have not found the solution to my problem anywhere though, even by searching and following the suggestions of several threads on StackExchange.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. I need to access machine C by doing:

```
laptop> ssh -X username@A
A> ssh -X username@B
B> ssh -X username@C
```

Machines A, B and C run CentOS 7.

Machines B and C share the same file system (the same `.ssh` folder, most notably). Needless to say, I get X11 forwarding issues. This is something related either to my own laptop, or to my account on one of these servers, because my colleagues do not have any trouble.
The error I get when trying to run e.g. `emacs` is:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Display localhost:20.0 unavailable, simulating -nw
```

I have tried the path of generating cookies with

```
> xauth add $DISPLAY - `mcookie`
> xauth nextract ~/xcookie3 $DISPLAY
```

and `scp`ing / merging them in the other machines, to no avail. I probably did something wrong, because I kept getting outputs like:

```
> xauth nmerge xcookie3
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to read any entries from file "xcookie3"
```

Can anyone advise on how to go around debugging this? I am at a loss. My `.bashrc` scripts look rather clean from my inexpert perspective. Not sure if I should purge my `.ssh` directories, which have been around for long and have been used for all sorts of other applications (pubkeys and the likes)... I will soon leave for teleworking, so I badly need to get this issue solved soon :(

Comment: The problem is likely that each stage somehow tries to involve a local X server, which it shouldn't, as you use A and B only as jumphosts. What happens if you use the jumphost syntax (`ssh -X -J username@A,username@B username@C`)? I've never tried this with X forwarding, but maybe it already does the right thing here...

Comment: First check the value of `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` on each intermediate host. For X11 forwarding to work, make sure that you let ssh do its thing and don't override anything on the server. From each intermediate host, try if an X program works (if none are installed, build and copy a small statically linked program). See where the chain breaks.

Comment: @Gilles I am not sure what you mean by "let ssh do its thing". The values of `DISPLAY` are `:0` for my laptop, `localhost:77.0` for A, `localhost:18.0` for B, `localhost:10.0` for C. However they tend to vary for A and B, as these are login servers and send me on a random node at each logon. `XAUTHORITY` is not set for A, B nor C; it points to `~/.Xauthority` on my laptop, a file with `-rw-------` permissions.

Comment: To debug I'd suggest you open a shell on laptop. Can you run `xeyes` (or any X application)? Then, after the first `ssh -X`, can you run `xeyes` on A (and see its output)? Move up the chain (connect to B) and, when it doesn't work, check the output in that host, right before the first prompt. There might be an `ssh` error there. Please share the result.